# XMLHttpRequest cannot load - Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, service, layer, hana

I am doing a login to connect through a service layer to a Linux server that has sap b1, and I get the following error.

> `XMLHttpRequest` cannot load https://hanab1:50000/b1s/v1/Login. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I find from Google Chrome and despite attempts, always the same error is generated, the funny thing is that when we perform the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilDH8nhnp4o, I get the error above dimensioned, but when I enter the URL directly the next line `https://hanab1:50000/B1S/v1`, see I have access to all information.

If anyone can help me in advance I thank you for your collaboration and interest.

Comment: Error message seems clear, you're passing withcredentials in xmlhttprequest, meaning the server has Access-Control-Allow-Credentials set to true, and then the allow-origin can't be a wildcard, you have to specifically set the allowed origin, or not use credentials.

Comment: @Jrg, Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, **you cannot**. To enable the Access Control, **you need to change** the way, the server sends you the headers. If your server is a PHP based one:

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

And for SAP (if it uses Apache), the headers should be:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

You can learn for other servers from here: [I want to add CORS support to my server](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).